# Creating a pie-chart that is filled up based on values excel?

Tags: python, excel, pie-chart

I want to create a Piechart in excel that fills up based on the values. So, it would have as many slices as rows in the table and based on the row's actual amount, it would fill up the slice accordingly. Below, I have presented a rough sketch of what I'm looking for in the piechart to explain it clearly. Assume there are 8 rows and the totals are out of 100; as no slice is full, there are no rows with 100 in their total. If you think there is a solution that can be coded in python then please could you suggest a place to look?

[image: Text]
Obviously not to scale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt to your question:

### Sample code:

```
# Create sample dataset:
index= ['A','B','C','D']
columns= ['pctLoad','pctTotal']
values= [[35,41],[39,12],[54,22],[27,25]]
df= pd.DataFrame(values, index=index, columns=columns, dtype= float)
```

| Index | pctLoad | pctTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 35 | 41 |
| B | 39 | 12 |
| C | 54 | 22 |
| D | 27 | 25 |

Assume `pctLoad` as the metric (percentage) by which the variable is used within its own limits, i.e. the bar chart. Where `pctTotal` represents the percentage share of each variable (A, B, C and D), i.e. the pie chart.

```
width= df['pctTotal']/100*2*np.pi
theta= [0]
for i, j in enumerate(width):
    theta.append(theta[-1] + j)
del(theta[-1])

fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize= (5, 5))
ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax.bar(theta, df['pctLoad'], width= width, align='edge', color= ['tab:blue', 'lightblue','grey', 'lightgrey'], alpha= 0.5, edgecolor= 'k')
ax.set_xticklabels([])
plt.show()
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: I'll be honest, it has been a while since I looked at this problem, but it's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bar chart on polar axis which is present in matplotlib

Sample code

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    # Fixing random state for reproducibility
    np.random.seed(19680801)

    # Compute pie slices
    N = 20
    theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
    radii = 10 * np.random.rand(N)
    width = np.pi / 4 * np.random.rand(N)
    colors = plt.cm.viridis(radii / 10.)

    ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
    ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.0, color=colors, alpha=0.5)

    plt.show()
```

[official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_bar.html?highlight=bar%20chart)